# mysterious reference error encountered (using node v 0.4.9)

Tags: node.js, referenceerror

I wrote a node program to scrape url content. Since a lot of things get thrown into and out the machine, I have a process listener for `uncaughtException` and just throw the error results into a log file instead of letting it kill the daemon.  Going over that log file recently, I noticed something amiss. Here's an error that gets thrown frequently and the stack trace:

Stack Trace:

> ReferenceError: GEL is not defined
>       at Object._onTimeout
>   (http://www.freep.com/article/20110809/ENT04/110809051/1001/news:undefined:undefined:2:25)
>       at Timer.callback (timers.js:83:39)

Not very informative I know. Naturally, I rgrepped my source code for `GEL`. Then I rgrepped all my node module dependencies (there's not that many) for `GEL`. Then I rgrepped node for `GEL`. Then I rgrepped v8 for `GEL`. Then I stopped and asked StackOverflow... What am I doing wrong? (I'm not doing anything too unreasonable in my code like trying to eval random strings or whatnot.)

Important: node v 0.4.9 ... think it also gets thrown on v 0.4.10

Comment: I don't have anything to add, just letting you know you're not getting ignored. I can't figure out what this is that's going on here either.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I figure it's more likely to be the fault of my code than node or v8 or scons obviously. I'll try to reproduce this again and then run some better debugging tools. (This isn't immediately easy to do because the daemon has a high throughput and will require a lot more logging to get the necessary pieces to reproduce it.)  I am still very bewildered as to how I'm getting the reference error though and there's no reference to `GEL` anywhere as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the problem.  It was in fact my code's fault.  The code I was debugging was using the `jsdom` module, which was interpreting the javascript from the web pages I was scraping.  I fixed the problem I was having by improving my `regex` that strips out `<script>` tags and passed an extra `features` argument to my `jsdom.env` call:

```
jsdom.env({
  html: myHtml, 
  done: myCallback,
  url: url,
  features : {
        FetchExternalResources       : [],
        ProcessExternalResources     : false
        }
});
```